# Position the date with dinbrief

Tags: positioning, letters, letterhead

How do I change the horizontal position of the date with dinbrief?

I have written some nice looking letters but now I am trying to align the date with part of my letterhead.  I'm using dinbrief and I cannot figure out how to change the horizontal position of the date.  The date (with location) are the only reference fields that I am using.  I am open to dirty hacks.

Here's a minimal document as a starting point:

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[10pt]{dinbrief}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Bill Bixby \\ 123 Hulk Rd. \\ Sheboygan, WI 01234}
  \opening{Dear Bill}
Long time no see.  Lorem ipsum etc.
  \closing{Kind Regards}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The date in [`dinbrief`](http://ctan.org/pkg/dinbrief) is set using `\raggedleft`. So, if you wish to move it it around, just include your spacing/formatting commands as part of the `\date` macro:

- `\date{\today\hspace{2em}}`: Date will be `2em` from the right margin
- `\date{\centering\today}`: Date will be centred
- `\date{\raggedright\today}`: Date will be flush left
- `\date{\raggedright\hspace{2em}\today}`: Date will be `2em` from the left margin

Here is a `\raggedright` display of `\today`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{dinbrief}% http://ctan.org/pkg/dinbrief
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\date{\raggedright\today}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Bill Bixby \\ 123 Hulk Rd. \\ Sheboygan, WI 01234}
  \opening{Dear Bill}
Long time no see.  Lorem ipsum etc.
  \closing{Kind Regards}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I ended up using \date{\today\hspace*{29 mm}}.  Note that you need \hspace* or the space at the end of the line will be ignored.